# How to prepare Windows 10 so that it can survive a complete change of motherboard and chipset without reinstall?

Tags: windows-10

I recently got a chance for a cheap upgrade to the aging PCs of my wife and myself. We both had Phenom II X2 CPUs with 10 year old motherboards and the new hardware has Gen 7 intel CPUs with respective motherboards. Not exactly new, but way better than what we have anyway.

I first tried upgrading my PC (just swapped out the MB/CPU/RAM but left everything else), however that didn't go so well. Windows couldn't boot with the error message `INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE`. I couldn't even get into Safe Mode! Interestingly the recovery Command Prompt *did* work and I could see my hard drive just fine. After spending several fruitless hours I finally caved in and reinstalled Windows.

But now I need to do the same on my wife's computer. I'm wondering - perhaps there are some preparations that will allow me to avoid a complete reinstall?

**Preemptive comment:** If anyone's worried about Windows activation, it's all good - we got Retail versions of Windows *precisely* because we knew we'd want to upgrade someday.

Comment: How to prepare Windows 10 so that it can survive a complete change of motherboard and chipset without reinstall?   .... Mostly no, and only with luck if it works.  Drivers and BIOS being the issue.

Comment: Going from a 10 or more year old system (possibly BIOS/CSM mode) to a modern UEFI system will not be easy, you are better off backing up the computers and then restoring on to a fresh operating system install.

Comment: Hmm, I just remembered about [`sysprep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview?view=windows-11). Could that maybe do the trick, or would it destroy too much information about the current user?

Comment: The Windows you had on the disk probably conflicted with the new motherboard/CPU. There may be a couple of BIOS settings that could help, but reinstalling is still the easiest.

Comment: When you upgrade more than just one piece of hardware, always reinstall. Yes, it is possible with lots of effort to migrate an install to different hardware, but experience tells me this always leads to problems and a slow install in the long run because of driver clutter. It is just not worth it. Backup, install fresh windows, and restore files from backup.

Comment: use sysprep to generalize the installation before moving to new pc>>>>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11